# Пропуск слов при оформлении цитат

Tags: цитаты

Нужно ли показывать пропуск слов при оформлении чужих слов с помощью косвенной речи или можно считать это элементом текста и не ставить знаки в начале (конце).

Допустим, было такое предложение: **"Члены семьи Лаптева считали себя умными и образованными".**

Я его могу процитировать так:

> Нам, читателям, понятно, что "члены семьи Лаптева считали себя умными"

Или нужно именно так:

> Нам, читателям, понятно, что "члены семьи Лаптева считали себя умными..."

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I5Z5a9gCKpc

Comment: Все-таки хочется услышать научные аргументы

Comment: Ну там девочка вроде объясняет, почему там какой знак, в том числе положение знаков до или после кавычек. 7 минута

Comment: Увы. Это не авторитет.

Comment: Тогда зовите авторитета, срочно)

Comment: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=163 56 параграф

Comment: .."члены семьи Лаптева считали себя умными..."**.** - точка в конце должна быть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кто цитирует, тому и решать. Если образованность Лаптевых не важна для цитирующего, он вправе оборвать цитату, где сочтёт нужным.

И кавычки необязательны - это же пересказ (*понятно, что* указует на факультативность донесения до слушателя каждого слова).

А отточие в конце сбивает с толку (то ли рассказчик задумался, то ли забыл, кем считают себя члены семьи Лаптева, то ли ожидайте продолжения). Или договаривайте до конца, или убирайте кавычки и ставьте точку.

*Нам, читателям, понятно, что члены семьи Лаптева считали себя умными.*

*Нам, читателям, понятно, что члены семьи Лаптева считали себя умными и образованными.*

---

Заголовок "Пропуск слов при оформлении цитат" не соответствует пояснению; на такой вопрос следовало бы рассказать о пропуске слов внутри цитаты,

но меня же никто не спрашивает об этом.

И даже при таком раскладе *понятно, что* допускает выборочное и незакавыченное цитирование, называемое

ПЕРЕСКАЗ СВОИМИ СЛОВАМИ.

Comment: ПО правилам же на месте пропущенного члена должно ставиться многоточие.

Comment: Но у нас же пересказ, к нему другие требования.